# Wix - How to get the default value of a registry key

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

Fairly straight forward question but can't seem to find an example on the net.

Currently I have the following wix snippet which, although the default value is set in the hkcr.gz registry key, is simply setting PREV_GZ_DEFAULT_APP to a blank empty string.

```
<Property Id="PREV_GZ_DEFAULT_APP">
   <RegistrySearch Id="Current_GZ_DEFAULT_APP"
                  Root="HKCR"
                  Key=".gz"
                  Name="(Default)"
                  Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

Any one know what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"(Default)" isn't a real name. To get the key's default value, just omit the Name attribute.

Comment: Thanks that worked as expected, I knew it would be simple! :)